# Is it possible to write screen recording software using Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I intend to develop a screen recording software.  Which is something similar to Microsoft's [Live Meeting](http://www.livemeetingplace.com/?gclid=CKzYr-_s9qcCFYd66wod1T24aw)

Is it possible to write such App using Silverlight ?

P.S,  the reason why I prefer is Silverlight is because of it's X-Platform support.

Comment: Check this out: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alon/archive/2010/07/06/screen-capture-in-silverlight-4-0.aspx

Comment: @Otaku, The link looks interesting. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight itself does not support screen grabs, so to get it working you would have to go outside of the Silverlight's sandbox.

With Silverlight 4 you can call external automation object (COM) to get screen shot and pass it to the application. Downsides for this approach are: requires elevated trust, windows only and requires additional install step.

Silverlight 5 will have support for P/Invoke and that should make things a bit easier. But that still leaves Mac out of the picture. In general I would say it is not worth doing it in Silverlight. Consider using .net + moonlight if portability is important to you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I started looking for other possibilities as you mentioned.  I believe it would be good to have this feature included Silverlight, Since Flex already has this support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the performance would be sufficiently good, but there is a CopyFromScreen method that will allow you to take screenshots from a given window. If you took screen shots at a sufficient frame rate you could stream them to the client.

See http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=303 for an example of how to capture the screenshots.

My understanding is bitmap sampling is a standard approach for this type of software.

Comment: @Amasuiel - I suppose, you are correct.  Bitmap sampling would be the right approach. But I am not sure whether we could do screen capturing using Silverlight.  My gut feeling(or atleast) I am hoping that this should be possible.  Since silverlight provide features like WebCam access. I appreciate your help. Thanks again !

Comment: The Bitmap and Graphic objects are part of the Silverlight runtime, so it should work fine (though I have not tested it for this purpose).